# Most effective way to make jquery field validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

what is the most effective way to make a jquery field validation? For example if field name is empty, it will add empty checkmark next to field? I understand, that PHP validation is needed, and I have it, so no worries about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try JQuery inline validation.

From here you can try out many examples 
http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

Comment: yes, totally agree, it's one of the best jQuery inline validation plugins - https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

Comment: just gotta say - this plugin is amazing and should be used by everyone.. form validation IS a mess